# Icon not showing in the input group

Tags: html, css, input, icons, bootstrap-5

I want to create an input group with text field and an icon at the beginning of the text field. I have the following code which shows only the text field and I cannot find out why the icon does not appear.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-text">
      <i class="fas fa-th-list"></i>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="Location">
</div>
```

How can I create an input group with an icon or input with an icon before the placeholder? What is wrong in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `form-group row`

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <label for="staticEmail" class="col-lg-1 col-form-label"><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i></label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="email@example.com">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it and the icon is still not available.

Comment: please make sure you import fontawesome icon correctly

Comment: Thank you. I found out that I had not imported the fontawesome icon. I added the cdn from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome and it worked.